# how can handle single quote in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i am working in php. i want to write query like this:-

```
update user_account set university_name='St. Josed father's institute' 
where userId=5;
```

but this is creating error due to **'s** means it creating problem because of single quote **'** .

please suggest me how can i handle this. currently i am right this directly **St. Josed father's institute**  but in my php code this is in variable 
$university_name

so please suggest me how can i check and remove such type of problem.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Duplicate of many of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+escape+quote

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$location = "St. Josed father's institute";
$location = mysql_real_escape_string($location);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = update user_account set university_name='St. Josed father's institute' 
where userId=5;

$query = str_replace("'","''", $query);
```

It's necessary that you realise this issue centers around SQL and not php. SQL's escape character (according to the standard 92) is '. So what we want to do is change

'St. Josed father's institute' to 'St. Josed father''s institute'

Using the escape character, mysql would not interpret you ' as the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

you could use php function mysql_real_escape_string

```
<?php
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
?>
```

document is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php